# parenthesis affecting the output in "c"

Tags: c

The program is for calculating summation of series 1/1! + 2/2! + .....
until the number given as input.

Here is the code I wrote.

/*I have used 5 variables and nested loops. I don't even know whether this is good way to write a program */

question: when I just put parenthesis as shown (below complete code) the output is different,
why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main ()
{
    int a,i,n;
    float sum=0,prod;
    printf ("Enter the number\n");
    scanf ("%d",&a);
    for (i=1;i<=a;i++)
    {   
        for (n=1;n<=i;n++)
        {   
            for (prod=1;n<=i;n++)
                prod = prod * 1/n;
        }
        sum = sum + prod*i;
    }
    printf ("sum = %f\n ",sum);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

with parenthesis

```
prod = prod * (1/n);
```

please help me with this and thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is integer division: 1/n = 0 for n > 1

Comment: http://c-faq.com/expr/truncation1.html

Comment: don't you learn about multiplication/division operator precedence in school?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C operates from left to right so it sees

```
prod = prod * 1 / N;
```

and it thinks prod is equal to prod by 1 then divided by n. By putting the brackets around 1 / N you tell C that prod is multiplied by 1/N instead of the other way. It is just like in Maths if you put brackets around something that will be evaluated separately and then placed back into the order on completion.

Answer (score 1):

> prod = prod * (1/n);  // wrong

This means `(1/n)` is done first - which is zero (as both treated as `int`, and 1 is less than `n`).

> prod = prod * 1/n;  // Correct

This means `prod * 1` is done first (association from left-to-right) - result is `double`, so final result `prod * 1/n` is also a double (which is correct result).

Comment: @DanielDowd `1/n` is zero, NOT `n` is zero

Answer (score 1):

`prod * 1/n` is parsed as `(prod * 1)/n` and results in a floating point division.

`prod * (1/n)` uses a integer division which wil truncate the result of the division (usually to 0).

Answer (score 1):

Without paranthesis the statement is parsed as

```
prod = (prod * 1) / n;
```

As `prod` is a float, `proad * 1` will be a float too. Then the division will be a floating-point division.

But, if you add paranthesis, then `(1/n)` will be a integer division because both operands are integers. Thus, `(1/n)` will be zero for `n` > 1. Then also `prod` will be zero.

Anyway, your program invokes undefined behaviour because `prod` has not been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Without parentheses the statement

```
prod = prod * 1/n;
```

will be parsed as

```
prod = (prod * 1) / n;
```

due to same precedence of `*` and `/` operands associate from left to right. In this case `prod * 1` is divided by `n`.

While in case of

```
prod = prod * (1/n);
```

`1/n` results in `0` always and causes different result. Changing it to

```
prod = prod * (1.0/n);
```

will work.

Comment: And what changes on the result? (The down vote is not mine)

Comment: @Frankie_C; `1/n` = 0

Comment: Clarify the answer then, as you wrote it makes not much sense.

Comment: @Frankie_C nothing in this answer that doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

```
int a,i,n;
float sum=0,prod;

prod = prod * (1/n);
```

Well , the answer is in your declarations: 1 and n are integers while prod is a float , the result of prod = prod * 1/n  = prod/n and the result will be the wanted correct float number.
While prod = prod * (1/n) will be prod * 0(for n>1) because 1/n is int/int and the result is an int.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one loop.  Here's how I'd write it in Java.  Converges quickly.  This series approximates the value of `e`.

```
package math.series;

/**
 * SeriesSum approximates value for e
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 2/20/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528818/parenthesis-effecting-the-output-in-c
 */
public class SeriesSum {

    public static final int DEFAULT_NUM_TERMS = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = (args.length > 0) ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : DEFAULT_NUM_TERMS;
        System.out.println(SeriesSum.summation(n));
    }

    public static double summation(int n) {
        double sum = 0.0;
        double term = 1.0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            term *= i;
            sum += i/term;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your code is not equivalent to the related math statement. Remember that the `/` in C is not division, it is **integer** division.

It effectively adds the math Floor function to your statement. In purely math terms, you are finding that:

`Prod * floor (1/n)` is different from `Floor (prod * 1/n)`.

You want the non parenthesized version in your code: `prod * 1/n`

But you will also need to add the remainder to your sum on each iteration, so:

`Prod = (prod /n) + (prod % n);`

Note that the parenthesis in this line of code is purely for your readability, it will not change the calculation.

Edit: I believe that in C if one of the operands on the `/` operator is a float, then it will carry out floating point division. If that's the case, you won't need to add the remainder into the sum:

`Prod = prod / n;`